what's the procedure if you can't establish communication with tower before landing under weather minimums IFR approach?
If for whatever reason(i.e. radio malfunction) you can't establish communication with tower before landing an IFR approach, what is the procedure to follow on that situation?

Gabe I voted to keep your question closed after your edit, because "busy towered airfield" in the other question implies a possibility for IFR conditions. In addition if it was reopened, it might be a duplicate of  Navigate to the final approach course after radio failure under IFR which has a very detailed answer including squawking 7600.
